# Using SES to send a personalised weekly digest email?

Tags: sql, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I am wondering where to start with setting up a weekly personalised digest to go out to my users (over 200k).

It would pull in content specific to them, we currently use SES for notifications, on a Windows EC2 instance with SQL.

Is there a cron style thing for windows IIS?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to develop a console application to send your emails and then use the windows task scheduler to schedule it to run once a week.

Within your console application you'll basically get your users from your database and foreach through each user getting whatever personalised data you need to build up an email message, and then pass off the message to Amazon SES.

To use Amazon SES you'll need to request a sending quota increase because the default quotas are way below what you need: Default sending quota is 10,000 emails per 24-hour period, and a maximum send rate of 5 emails per second.

Answer (score 1):

To implement this functionality you'll need these components:

1. Some application that will collate all bits of information and create an email message. Probably same app will send to email server (SES). If every message is unique to the user then 
   Hence the Question: How can I send email message programmatically?

   - Write your script. C# or any other language. It needs to connect to db, extract either pieces of email body or whole message will be collated by SQL query / SP. it will also extract email addresses and send the email.
   - You can use SSIS to create process of getting of needed bits, and sendin emails. It offers graphical interface for the process map. It may be not so fast as a custom script, but scheduling is very simple with SQL Server Agent. Also you can implement various processes depending on run time calculations.
   - Use and other soft to create and send emails (except Mail Merge in MS Word, joking )
2. Scheduling tool, that will run app from 1 on regular basis.

   - Use windows scheduling tool
   - SQL Server Agent. You can run SQL scripts and stored procedures. Scripts and SPs can contain file system commands (call .exe files, read data from files, etc), but you'll need to do some research for syntax, functionality and necessary permissions.
   - There are other scheduling apps available.
3. Content control. It may me done by the app, but you'll create some tables or use files for settings, common parts of the email message etc.

   - You would wish to keep record of various rules used to create custom messages. Logic

Generic advice. For the first time go with software you are familiar with. Solution may be cumbersome, but longest way is taking shortcuts.

There are many mass mailing and mail merge applications around. You can find those easily, compare functionality and may be choose one of those.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of the library mentioned below.

You could be interested by the library I'm writing. It's called [nvelopy](http://nvelopy.com). I created it so that it's easy to embed in a .Net application to send transactional emails and campaigns. That way, it can directly access your data (users) to create a segment and send it via Amazon while respecting the sending quota.

I developed it for my own web service. I didn't want to setup another server or export/import users and I wanted it to "talk" to my datastore (RavenDb). A SQL datastore connector is also in the works.

Let me know if you have any question (via the contact page of the nvelopy web site).